# SwiftによるCSVファイルの生成方法

Tags: swift, iphone, csv

アプリ内で選択したデータをCSVファイルにし、
メーラーを呼び出し、
メールに添付させて送信させたいのですが、
どのようにしたら良いのかわかりません。

自力で調べてもCSVファイルの読み込み方法しかなかったため、
苦戦しております。

よろしければご教授下さい。
よろしくお願い致します。

追加************
別々の内容のcsvファイルを2つ添付したい場合はどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

`MFMailComposeViewController`というクラスを使うと、アプリから簡単にiPhoneのメーラーを呼び出すことができます。（添付ファイルも設定できるので、ご質問の用途にピッタリだと思います。）

```
func sendMailWithCSV(subject: String, message: String, csv: [[String]]) {
    let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailVC.setSubject(subject)
    mailVC.setMessageBody(message, isHTML: false)
    mailVC.addAttachmentData(toCSV(csv)
        .dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        , mimeType: "text/csv"
        , fileName: "data.csv")
    self.presentViewController(mailVC, animated: true) {}
}
```

また、文字列の多次元配列からCSV文字列を作る`toCSV`は以下のページを参考に書きました。
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-Separated_Values

```
func toCSV(a: [[String]]) -> String {
    return join("\n", a.map { join(",", $0.map { e in
        contains(e) { contains("\n\",", $0) } ?
            "\"" + e.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "\"\"", options: nil, range: nil) + "\"" : e
    })}) + "\n"
}
```